# Preprocessor Macros for Abstraction - Good Practice?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it considered good practice to use a transparent macro to abstract away implementation details? Like so:

```
#define valuePointer struct value*

struct list {
  valuePointer* listData;
  int length;
}
```

In my opinion, the macro makes the code cleaner and abstracts away the `struct value** listData` that ought to go there. But it's kind of a useless macro; just directly meaning `value*`. Is this ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C has typedef for that

```
typedef struct value* valuePointer ;
```

Only hide the `*` in the typedef if you have a good reason for it.

Comment: why struct? doesn't make any sense here

Comment: @Lectem It makes perfect sense.

Comment: It was my thought that `typedef` creates a new type. Is that not correct? (EDIT: I see it's not after a quick look on Google.)

Comment: @CalebP It does not. Typedef gives you a new name for an existing type.

Comment: @2501 sorry but in the original question the struct wasn't present

Comment: @Lectem yeah sorry I edited it a few minutes after writing it.

Comment: So does abstracting the use of the struct pointer count as a good reason?

Comment: Otherwise I have to use double asterisks everywhere

Comment: @CalebP I would only do it if I was unable to write the code otherwise.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why, or is it just because it might be misleading? I think `valuePointer` seems to be a pretty clear map to `struct value*`.

Comment: @CalebP There are plenty of similar question on SO with good answers. Use search.

Answer (score 1):

Not for this kind of usage, typedef was made to do what you just did, eg :

```
typedef struct value* valuePointer.
```

Defines are quite dangerous if you don't master them, but can be very efficient in some cases. In my opinion you should use it when dealing with different types needing same functions. For example if you wish to get the square of numbers :

```
#define SQUARE(i) ((i)*(i))
```

As you can see I added a lot of parentheses, because it really is dangerous.

I personally only see the needs of "abstracting" pointers when you have 3 layers or more of pointers, otherwise dereferencing twice is no big deal.

Comment: Even with all those parentheses, SQUARE(*p++) will have an unexpected result. These days, it is usually better to trust the compiler to inline.

Comment: Of course and that's why I said it is dangerous, imho, use defines only if you perfectly understand what it does and how it works.